# Show that $4xf''(x)+2f'(x)=f(x)$

Tags: derivatives

$f(x)=e^{\sqrt{x}}$

Show that $4xf''(x)+2f'(x)=f(x)$

I got $f'(x)=\ln^2x$ and $f''(x)=(2-2\ln x)/x^2$

I try sub $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ into $4xf''(x)+2f'(x)=f(x)$

I got $\ln x(8+2\ln x)$ 
Not sure what to do next

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know where you got the logarithm. If $f(x)=e^{\sqrt{x}}$, then $$f'(x)=e^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ by the chain rule.

Comment: OMG the (a)part of this question is to find $f^-1(x)$ My writing  are too messy and I Mess up the numbers Thanks

Comment: I just sit there for like half an hour and wondering which part I did wrong  OMG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that,
$$f(x^2)=e^x$$
Differentiate both sides,
$$2xf'(x^2)=e^x$$
Again differentiate both sides,
$$4x^2f''(x^2)+2f'(x^2)=e^x=f(x^2)$$
Replace $x^2$ by $x$ and you are done!

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear where you got logarithms from. $f'(x)=e^{\sqrt x} (\frac  1 2 x^{-1/2})$ and $f''(x)= e^{\sqrt x}(-\frac 1 4x^{-3/2}+\frac 1 4 x^{-1})$. Now plug these values into LHS and see if you get $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=e^{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{f(x)}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{4x\sqrt{x}}(\sqrt{x}-1)=\frac{f(x)}{4x}(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})$$